# Simple texture blending of >2 PBR materials

Tags: texturing

I have been trying to find a simple way of blending multiple textures as in game engines (splat mapping as its known). I have seen tutorials for how to do this but they all involve elaborate node setups and i dont think they can handle more than 2 textures. are there any tools available for this? it seems like a fundamental requirement when building large scale environments.Thanks